# Does session timeout in ASP.NET use server system time

Tags: asp.net, session

Does it use server time? If I set timeout to 1 hour in web.config, run the application, then I increase the system time to +58 minutes, will it timeout after 2 minutes?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: add necessary code which have issue.